# How to generate db schema from entities using annotation configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have bunch of java POJO classes. I previously generated schema with XML configuration but now I am using annotated and it doesn't work.

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.library.entities");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");


        return dataSource;
    }

    final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.database", "MYSQL");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl", "create");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
```

My properties are set up in entityManagerFactory. The logger info that can be helpful:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:462 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I don't have hibernate.properties file. Is this file necessary in Annotated configuration?

```
INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keys for properties are wrong.
Keys like `spring.jpa.*` are for Spring Boot when you are defining configs in `application.properties` file.

Take a look at the [AvailableSettings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html) interface to see available and valid keys.

So the keys must be:

```
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

OR

```
hibernateProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, "true");
hibernateProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
```